# how to create folder in root of SD card or phone storage in Android usin Cordova plugin

Tags: android, cordova, mobile

I am try to create folder in the location of phone storage or SD using following code using cordova in android devices.

```
function onDeviceReady() {
window.requestFileSystem = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.externalRootDirectory,onFileSystemSuccess,onError);

}

function onFileSystemSuccess(fileSystem) {
        var entry = "";
        if (device.platform.toLowerCase() == "android") {
            entry = fileSystem;
        } else {
            entry = fileSystem.root;
        }
        entry.getDirectory("SampleFolder", {
            create: true,
            exclusive: false
        }, onGetDirectorySuccess, onGetDirectoryFail);
    };
    
     function onError(e) {
        alert("Fail to get folder");
    };
    
    
     function onGetDirectorySuccess(dir) {
        dir.getFile(filename, {
            create: true,
            exclusive: false
        }, gotFileEntry, errorHandler);
    };

  function onGetDirectoryFail(dir) {
        alert("Fail to get folder");
    };

    function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {

        alert(fileEntry);

        // logic to write file in respective directory
    };


    function errorHandler(e) {
        // handle error
    }
```

This is Androidmanifest.xml

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
 <manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="5"    android:versionName="1.1.1" package="xxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/display_name" android:supportsRtl="true" android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"  android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
    <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/display_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <provider android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true" android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
    </provider>
    <receiver android:enabled="true" android:name="nl.xservices.plugins.ShareChooserPendingIntent">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <provider android:authorities="${applicationId}.sharing.provider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true" android:name="nl.xservices.plugins.FileProvider">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/sharing_paths" />
    </provider>
</application>
<uses-sdk android:maxSdkVersion="30" android:minSdkVersion="15" android:targetSdkVersion="29" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

This code create folder in Android version 6 devices only, but not create in android version 10.

Pls help me to achive this to create folder in all versions of android devices (version 4 to version 10)

Note : cordova-plugin-file 4.3.3 version added in my project and in android ver 6 can create folder, but in ver 10 cant.

What i tried based on below reply, i added this line  android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" in andoridmanifest.xml i will get error when i build using node.js screenshot -http://prntscr.com/vtften

Error

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 3.553 secs

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
  Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
  F:\Mobile Projects\1652019\FingerTips\OAMobile\platforms\android\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:31: AAPT: No resource identifier found for attribute 'requestLegacyExternalStorage' in package 'android'

F:\Mobile Projects\1652019\FingerTips\OAMobile\platforms\android\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:31: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'requestLegacyExternalStorage' in package 'android'

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Regards and Thanks
Aravind

Comment: Request legacy external storage in manifest file for Android 10 devices.

Comment: After adding android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"  in Application tag in androidmanifest.xml file, i am getting error when build screenshot - http://prntscr.com/vtae44

Comment: Which error do you get and when?

Comment: when i build in node.js after adding android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"  , i will get this error screenshot -http://prntscr.com/vtae44  , http://prntscr.com/vtfmfx

Comment: If you have errors then put them as text in your post. Not in a comment please.

Comment: hi, in text cant put full, that's y i put as screenshot.Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

Comment: Sorry but in this way help can not be given.

Comment: hi above i updated description with error screenshot, actually build error appear after adding android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" this line in andoridmanifest.xml which is recommend by you, that's y i reply in ur comment itself.